# Solve $\sin(2x)+\cos(x)-2\sin(x)-1=0,$ for $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$

Tags: trigonometry

Solve $$\sin(2x)+\cos(x)-2\sin(x)-1=0,\quad x\in[-\pi,\pi].$$

I tried to make this into a quadratic equation so that I could solve for $x$ by converting $\sin(2x)$ into $2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ and then rearranging it somehow. Am I on the right track or not? Both ways, could I be offered a hint to the problem first rather than answers? Thanks very much!

Comment: You're on the right track. All you need to do now is to express cos(x) using sin(x). That you can do using one very important trigonometric formula.

Comment: @Keen Normally I'd agree with you, but I don't think OP even needs to go that far. The expression should just factorise.

Comment: $2 \sin x \cos x+ \cos x - 2\sin x = 2 \sin x(\cos x - 1)+(\cos x -1) = \ldots$

Comment: @Kevin thanks! I couldn't think of that somehow... Is it because of lack of experience in solving these problems?

Comment: @InfiniteAccelerator0643 Well, I would put it down to practice makes perfect..the more examples you undertake and the tricks and substitutions you pick up on the way means that you'll smash these types of problems in no time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: $$\cos(x)(2\sin(x)+1)-(2\sin(x)+1)=0$$ and this is $$(2\sin(x)+1)(\cos(x)-1)=0$$